# Best SQL DB structure for stock market data

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to store stock data in a MySQL DB, but I'm unsure about the most efficient way to structure it. In summary, I have many tickers to store and each has many records (consisting of a date and a price). My queries will be for a range of dates (ex. prices of stock X from date1 to date2). Any ideas for an efficient way to structure these to minimize query times for this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entirety of your use cases, then it's just as simple as creating the following tables:

1. `Tickers` for the unique list of stock tickers. It probably will have the columns `(TickerId, TickerName)`.
2. `Prices` for each price of a stock as of a given datetime. It can have the columns `(PriceId, TickerId, Price, AsOfDateTime)`. It will have a foreign key relationship from `Prices.TickerId` to `Tickers.TickerId`.

You will want to create an index on the `Prices` table for the following columns as such `(TickerId, AsOfDateTime, Price)`. This will allow you to efficiently search for a set of prices for a given ticker over a range of dates. A B-Tree index has a search time complexity of `O(Log(n))` so it will be very fast to find a subset of the data, even with billions of records in the table.

I'll leave the data types for you to decide, and feel free to add more meta-data columns as needed.

Comment: Toss `PriceID`, instead, have `PRIMARY KEY(TickerId, AsOfDateTime)`.  This will make more operations noticeably faster.  Also have `INDEX(AsOfDateTime)` if you want all the prices for a given day.

Comment: @RickJames Just curious, why would the implicit clustered index from making that the primary key be any faster than a covering nonclustered index in this case? (But true, at the least writes can be faster by not needing to manage an additional index since making that the clustered index will work in this use case too.)

Comment: Point taken.  There may be more columns added, thereby adding more considerations.  (On 2/3 of the tables that I create, I find that I can do without an auto_inc.)

Comment: My two cents, having `PRIMARY KEY(TickerId, AsOfDateTime)`  will guarantee fragmentation of your clustered index.   I would advise against it.